# SVN Merge Visual studio 2008 projects into 2010 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Our product has got some different active branches in SVN. We are thinking to upgrade only the trunk to VS2010 while keeping earlier version(couple of active development versions) in VS2008.

In that case will we be able to merge 2008 projects into VS2010 projects. Has anybody done this ? Is this can be problamatic?

Both VS2008 and VS2010 has the same structure for project files, solution files and resx files? Will I be able to merge them without any issue?

We are using C# as the programming language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a VS 2008 project. There is a VS 2008 solution and a VS 2010 solution. A VS 2010 solution can contain projects **targeted for various .NET frameworks:** you van have one project targeted for framework 3.5 and another targeted for framework 4.0.

There is no problem in doing so, you can use classes defined in a 3.5 assembly from a 4.0 assembly and have both of them in one VS 2010 solution.

Comment: isn't a .vcproj file a VS 2008 project? (or even VS 2005)

Comment: @stijn: Yes, but this question is about C#, not C++.  C# project files didn't change nearly as much.